# SDL x and y movement

Tags: c++, sdl

Why wont this code let me move up or left?

```
while( quit == false )
    { 


    apply_surface( 0,0, back,screen );
    apply_surface( playerx,playery,player, screen );


    SDL_Flip( screen );

        //While there's an event to handle
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_UP:playery=playery-10;
                case SDLK_DOWN:playery=playery+10;
                case SDLK_LEFT:playerx=playerx-10;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:playerx=playerx+10;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `break` after each `case` in the `switch`  Otherwise the execution "falls through" to the next line, potentially cancelling your action (and indeed `SDLK_UP` and `SDLK_LEFT` are the ones where the cancellation happens)

Comment: yes indeed that worked ty (realy need to be more careful and read stuff before i ask)